# Program Does Not Execute as Expected

Tags: shell-script, logs, gnu-screen

I have the following bash shell script which 90% of the time does the expected thing, but sometimes it doesn't. The problem is with the placement of the date and time. As shown, I have told the program to append the `date` at the end of `screenlog.0`. Most of the time, this happens properly. However, sometimes the date and time get appended to the *beginning* of `screenlog.0`. This is really troublesome as the format of `screenlog.0` needs to adhere to certain guidelines. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
...
...

if grep -q "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" MasterFile.txt || [ -e "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}" ];
then
   echo "dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2} already exists in the MasterFile or the current directory. Would you like to proceed?"
   read string3
   if [[ "${string3^}" == 'Y' ]]; then
      echo "How many times has this dicounter been retested? (e.g. 1 for first time, 2 for the second, ...)"
      read string4
      screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
      screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
      sleep 8s
      screen -S trans -X quit
      date +%F~%H:%M:%S >> screenlog.0
      mv screenlog.0 dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}~${string4}

   else
      exit 0
   fi
else
  #opening screen & begin analysis
  screen -S trans -L /dev/ttyACM0
  screen -S trans -X stuff 's'$(echo -ne '\015')
  sleep 8s
  screen -S trans -X quit
  date +%F~%H:%M:%S >> screenlog.0
  mv screenlog.0 dicounter_${string1}_from_${string2}

fi
```

Essentially, the program is to look to see if the `dicounter_..._from_...` already exists, and if not, or if the user wants another test run, proceed and connect to a transmitter and take data. At the end, a `screenlog.0` file is created, to which I want to append the date and time at the end of the file. Then rename it.

Comment: you're appending the output, so my only theory is that `screen` hasn't written the file when you call `date`, and so `date` creates a new file. The only workaround I can think of would be adding `sleep`s in-between, or perhaps a busy-loop checking for a non-zero size of screenlog.0

Comment: Or just add a `;date` to the command you're `stuff`ing into the `screen` session.

Comment: Yes, it was the premature appending that was the issue. I added `sleep 2s` and for now its all good.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please consider (voting) and clicking the checkmark to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the screen "quit" command was returning before flushing the log. Adding a delay between the final screen command and the datestamp should allow time for screen to finish writing to the log. Another option would be to use a "busy" loop to wait for the log to be written to:

```
...
screen -S trans -X quit
while [ ! -s screenlog.0 ]
do
  sleep 1
done
date +%F~%H:%M:%S >> screenlog.0
...
```